# Python 3.10 silent install for all users is NOT shown in Add remove program for all users

Tags: windows-installer, python-3.10

I am installing python 3.10 in windows 2019 box uisng command.
Python is promprtly installed and able to check the same in command line and in control panel -> 'Uninstall or change the  Program'for the user who installed it.
The programs are listed as 'Python Launcher' and 'Python 3.10.0 (64bit) for user who installed it.

However the 'Uninstall or change the  Program' in control panel does not list the Python 3.10.0 and Python launcher for otherusers . Why this issue happening and how to resolve it?

(1) Install command -  C:\Software\python310\python-3.10.0-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 TargetDir=C:\Python310 Include_launcher=1 /log "C:\Temp\Python310-Install.log"
(2) Installed user is having admin right
(3) All users are admin users.No luck even after reboot to other users
(4) Os win 2019 64 bit

Comment: Ideally, InstallAllUsers=1 should do the work. Can you check msi install log for ALLUSERS=1?

Comment: Vivek Jaiswal - part of log pasted here. Initially, it was zero and set to 1 later part.[0DDC:0DC0][2022-08-29T21:06:00]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value '0' -----later part of log has [0DDC:0588][2022-08-29T21:06:01]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value 1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug with python and no fix right now for this version . Doumented at
https://bugs.python.org/issue46714